XPATH: quiero seleccionar un checbox de una lista. Su descripción si es única, pero está en otro nivel y si hago click en la descripción no la marca
Quiero seleccionar una opción de un formulario WEB y aunque el checkbox y la descripción están juntas, en el html están a distintos niveles. La descripción de la opción si es única y puedo llegar a ella, pero no se como llegar al checbox para marcarlo, puesto que si en la descripción hago click no lo marca, tiene que ser en el div que contiene solo el checkbox o en el mismo input de tipo checkbox, lo que ocurre es que no identifico ninguna cosa que sea única. Todos los ids son dinámicos.

Agradecería me pudierais ayudar.

Puedes probar seleccionar el elemento span con //span[. = 'Código del proveedor'], el elemento td con //span[. = 'Código del proveedor']/ancestor::td[1], entonces el otro elemento td con //span[. = 'Código del proveedor']/ancestor::td[1]/preceding-sibling::td[1] y finalmente el elemento input con //span[. = 'Código del proveedor']/ancestor::td[1]/preceding-sibling::td[1]//input[@type = 'checkbox'].
